# What is the meaning of "right there"? Does it mean "inside that thing"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm watching a comedy movie called *Bad Trip* (2020). There are 2 male friends riding in a car. One of them who is in the passenger seat picks a DVD snap case and the driver, owner of the car, says: "That's my favorite movie right there, man."

Does "right there", in this context, mean "inside that DVD snap case" or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is casual and conversational, but there is no mystery.

The adverb "right" is used for emphasis, to emphasise the precise location. And the location is  "there": literally close to the person he is talking to (contrast with "right here")  And so "right there" means "exactly where you are" or "In your hands" or "in front of your eyes".

The expression is redundant. But conversational speech is frequently redundant.